# How to UPDATE a column from two possible database sources

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following scenario:

```
Database A.table A.name
Database A.table A.Application

Database B.table B.name
Database B.table B.Application

Database C.table C.name
Database C.table C.Application
```

I'm trying to write an UPDATE query that will set a value to table A.Application. The value I need to update it with could come from tables B or C but not both; A.name only exists in either B or C. The condition for each row I would need to update on would be as so:

```
If B.name exists for A.name, set A.Application = B.application
If C.Name exists for A.name, set A.application = C.application
```

I'm trying to do this non-dynamically; any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: ` tables B or C but not both` you need to give a priority to one or the other unless you really want it to be arbitrary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two statements:

```
UPDATE A 
SET A.Application = B.Application
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.name = B.name;

UPDATE A 
SET A.Application = C.Application
FROM A
INNER JOIN C ON A.name = C.name;
```

Only one of them will actually do anything to the data, assuming the names in B and C are truly orthogonal.  Otherwise, C wins.

Or you could get fancy (without having actually tried it):

```
UPDATE A 
SET A.Application = ISNULL(B.Application, C.Application)
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.name = B.name
LEFT JOIN C ON A.name = C.name
```

Comment: This is largely correct except how you're referencing the tables is wrong. See [Using Identifiers As Object Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879(SQL.105).aspx) In this case the following will probably work `FROM A..Table A LEFT JOIN B..table B ON A.name = B.name`

Comment: Only issue I see with the "fancy" solution is if A does not exist in B or C.  It would update the application to null in that case.  Not sure if this is an issue for OP's data though.  Could get around it by inner joining a union all of B and C.

Comment: @Zhenny no need for an inner join just `WHERE ISNULL(B.Application, C.Application) is not null` or `SET A.Application = COALESCE(B.Application, C.Application, A.Application)`

Comment: @Zhenny - bluefeet mentioned that "A.name only exists in either B or C", so I assumed it holds true that A.name would never not be in one or the other.

Comment: @Conrad - I'm not sure I understand why four-part naming plays into it.  Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: @jonnyGold the question title "two possible *database* sources" and the names *Database* A.table, *Database* B.table ... indicate that the tables are in different databases. If you need to refer to objects that are in a different database then you need to use at least 3 part names, 4 if they're on different server.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggested code and comments. I ended up using the "fancy" suggestion by @jonnyGold as modified by Conrad Frix to use the 3-part naming and COALESCE function. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @A table([name] varchar(1),[Application] int)
insert @A
select 'a',0 union all
select 'b',0 union all
select 'c',0
declare @B table([name] varchar(1),[Application] int)
insert @B
select 'a',5 union all
select 'b',6
declare @C table([name] varchar(1),[Application] int)
insert @C
select 'c',8

update @A set [Application]=b.[Application]
from @A a left join
(
select [name],[Application] from @B
union all
select [name],[Application] from @C
) b on a.name=b.name

select * from @A
/*
name Application
---- -----------
a    5
b    6
c    8
*/
```